# Return multiple fields as a record in PostgreSQL with PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, types, plpgsql

I am writing a SP, using PL/pgSQL.
I want to return a record, comprised of fields from several different tables. Could look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields(name text)
  RETURNS RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
  -- fetch fields f1, f2 and f3 from table t1
  -- fetch fields f4, f5 from table t2
  -- fetch fields f6, f7 and f8 from table t3
  -- return fields f1 ... f8 as a record
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

How may I return the fields from different tables as fields in a single record?

**[Edit]**

I have realized that the example I gave above was slightly too simplistic. Some of the fields I need to be retrieving, will be saved as separate rows in the database table being queried, but I want to return them in the 'flattened' record structure.

The code below should help illustrate further:

```
CREATE TABLE user (id int, school_id int, name varchar(32));

CREATE TYPE my_type AS (
  user1_id   int,
  user1_name varchar(32),
  user2_id   int,
  user2_name varchar(32)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_two_users_from_school(schoolid int)
  RETURNS my_type AS $$
DECLARE
  result my_type;
  temp_result user;
BEGIN
  -- for purpose of this question assume 2 rows returned
  SELECT id, name INTO temp_result FROM user where school_id = schoolid LIMIT 2;
  -- Will the (pseudo)code below work?:
  result.user1_id := temp_result[0].id ;
  result.user1_name := temp_result[0].name ;
  result.user2_id := temp_result[1].id ;
  result.user2_name := temp_result[1].name ;
  return result ;
END
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Did investigate returning multiple records e.g. `returns setof my_type`

Comment: @nate: its not the function that returns a set. I need to fetch records WITHIN the SP, and then retrieve fields from INDIVIDUAL records in the retrieved set, in the data returned from the function - sounnds more complicated than it actually is - see the code above

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to define a new type and define your function to return that type.

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (f1 varchar(10), f2 varchar(10) /* , ... */ );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields(name text) 
RETURNS my_type 
AS 
$$

DECLARE
  result_record my_type;

BEGIN
  SELECT f1, f2, f3
  INTO result_record.f1, result_record.f2, result_record.f3
  FROM table1
  WHERE pk_col = 42;

  SELECT f3 
  INTO result_record.f3
  FROM table2
  WHERE pk_col = 24;

  RETURN result_record;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you want to return more than one record you need to define the function as `returns setof my_type`

---

**Update**

Another option is to use `RETURNS TABLE()` instead of creating a `TYPE` which was introduced in Postgres 8.4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields(name text) 
  RETURNS TABLE (f1 varchar(10), f2 varchar(10) /* , ... */ )
...
```

Comment: Please see the modified question - it turns out the original question was too simplified for my actual needs. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "new" problem, but it all boils down to finding the correct queries that retrieve the desired result. Once you have them, returning the result should not be a problem

Comment: The new problem is that I need to be able to offset into retrieved rows and fetch specific fields from the retrieved set, so that I can populate the 'flattened' structure that is returned from the SP. The new problem boils down to the following two questions: (1). what data type do I use to receive a set of rows from a query (2)> How do I access field "f1" of the Nth row in the returned set?

Comment: I would suggest to open a new question for this. In a nutshell: for 1) you would use a cursor to iterate over the result and pick the ones you need, for 2) you keep a counter e.g. using row_number() that identifies the specific row. Or even better: only select *that* row. But all that will not change the signature of your function. It is enough to return the type you have specified.

Comment: Don't use a new `TYPE` to solve this problem. Just use a `RECORD` and alias the members in the `RECORD`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547672/how-to-return-multiple-fields-as-a-record-in-postgresql-pl-pgsql/6085167#6085167 for a more correct answer that doesn't involve custom `TYPE`s.

Comment: What will happen in a case where the query has 0 results? The function will still return one row (result_record my_type ) with null values all though its expected to return 0 rows

Comment: As of 9.4 the correct syntax requires the 'AS' modifier, so the example above would be : CREATE TYPE my_type AS (f1 varchar(10), f2 varchar(10), ... );

Comment: Would be nice if this possible: `RETURNS TABLE( auto )` which will not require to use `from my_fn() as ( field type, field, type )` as for `RETURNS SETOF record`

Answer (score 166):

Don't use [CREATE TYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) to return a polymorphic result. Use and abuse the [RECORD type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) instead. Check it out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_ret(a TEXT, b TEXT) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
  -- Arbitrary expression to change the first parameter
  IF LENGTH(a) < LENGTH(b) THEN
      SELECT TRUE, a || b, 'a shorter than b' INTO ret;
  ELSE
      SELECT FALSE, b || a INTO ret;
  END IF;
RETURN ret;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Pay attention to the fact that it can optionally return **two** or **three** columns depending on the input.

```
test=> SELECT test_ret('foo','barbaz');
             test_ret             
----------------------------------
 (t,foobarbaz,"a shorter than b")
(1 row)

test=> SELECT test_ret('barbaz','foo');
             test_ret             
----------------------------------
 (f,foobarbaz)
(1 row)
```

This does wreak havoc on code, so do use a consistent number of columns, but it's ridiculously handy for returning optional error messages with the first parameter returning the success of the operation. Rewritten using a consistent number of columns:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_ret(a TEXT, b TEXT) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
  -- Note the CASTING being done for the 2nd and 3rd elements of the RECORD
  IF LENGTH(a) < LENGTH(b) THEN
      ret := (TRUE, (a || b)::TEXT, 'a shorter than b'::TEXT);
  ELSE
      ret := (FALSE, (b || a)::TEXT, NULL::TEXT);
   END IF;
RETURN ret;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Almost to epic hotness:

```
test=> SELECT test_ret('foobar','bar');
   test_ret    
----------------
 (f,barfoobar,)
(1 row)

test=> SELECT test_ret('foo','barbaz');
             test_ret             
----------------------------------
 (t,foobarbaz,"a shorter than b")
(1 row)
```

But how do you split that out in to multiple rows so that your ORM layer of choice can convert the values in to your language of choice's native data types? The hotness:

```
test=> SELECT a, b, c FROM test_ret('foo','barbaz') AS (a BOOL, b TEXT, c TEXT);
 a |     b     |        c         
---+-----------+------------------
 t | foobarbaz | a shorter than b
(1 row)

test=> SELECT a, b, c FROM test_ret('foobar','bar') AS (a BOOL, b TEXT, c TEXT);
 a |     b     | c 
---+-----------+---
 f | barfoobar | 
(1 row)
```

This is one of the coolest and most underused features in PostgreSQL. Please spread the word.

Comment: Indeed handy.. I was wondering how to split this record again... Thanks!

Comment: @Sean: Great answer thanks -- I'm going to try this. And splitting out the results in the last example is very cool.

Comment: @Sean: Thanks. I find the `SELECT a, b, c ...` very useful. How could I use that method with something like: `SELECT code, theFunction(code) from theTable ;`, where I am `SELECT`ing from the *table* rather than the function?

Comment: @SabreWolfy, you can't to the best of my knowledge unless you make `theFunction` a set-returning function.

Comment: @Sean can u please let me know that what is the way to return multiple rows from RECORD type ??

Comment: @SatishSharma Use a sub-SELECT and the crosstab contrib function. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: `RETURNS record` is a measure of last resort. It forces you to provide the column definition list with every call, which is very unwieldy. There are almost always better ways. Also: [There are ways to have *actual* polymorphic results with polymorphic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557).

Comment: Absolutely it can be unwieldy, but `EXECUTE` forces the contents of the [`EXECUTE` command to be re-planned every time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), whereas normal SQL statements in pl/PgSQL will cache the query plan. There's certainly a tradeoff between the two approaches to solve this. I prefer the explicit and more unwieldy approach over dynamic SQL construction and execution, especially in `SECURITY DEFINER` contexts.

Comment: @Sean: 1. Since Postgres 9.2, plain SQL statements are re-planned, too. [Details here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359835/postgres-function-much-slower-when-using-input-variables/16363135#16363135) 2. The return type is *independent* of `EXECUTE` or not. 3. The technique in the answer only works for single-row results not for `SETOF record`. 4. If your return type is constant anyway (like in your example), use a well known type. The idea with an anonymous record only makes sense in rare cases with varying return types.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter 1) Yes, 9.2 hadn't been released when I wrote this answer. 4) I've found it particularly useful as a way of returning multiple columns worth of information from a function. It's not a universal solution, but returning multiple typed and named elements from a function is nice.

Comment: What will happen in a case where the query has 0 results? The function will still return one row (ret RECORD ) even though its expected to return 0 rows.

Comment: This is wrong, don't fall into this trap, it works as he says, but this makes the code integrity depends on columns order of the table, this MUST not be tolerated because eventually the column order of the table will change and highly likely would be different between development and deployment.

Comment: @Raiden Why would the column order "eventually" (when?) change?

Comment: You are not planning to make your development machine the same as your production machine, in PostgreSQL all mirroring solutions are forced to change the column order, not their fault, this is how PostgreSQL is made, you can not even change the column order in commands, this unique to postgresql

Answer (score 79):

#### To return a single row

Simpler with [**`OUT`** parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields(_school_id int
                                       , OUT user1_id   int
                                       , OUT user1_name varchar(32)
                                       , OUT user2_id   int
                                       , OUT user2_name varchar(32)) AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO user1_id, user1_name
          u.id, u.name
   FROM   users u
   WHERE  u.school_id = _school_id
   LIMIT  1;  -- make sure query returns 1 row - better in a more deterministic way?

   user2_id := user1_id + 1; -- some calculation

   SELECT INTO user2_name
          u.name       
   FROM   users u
   WHERE  u.id = user2_id;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM get_object_fields(1);
```

- You don't *need* to create a type just for the sake of this plpgsql function. It *may* be useful if you want to bind multiple functions to the same composite type. Else, `OUT` parameters do the job.
- There is no `RETURN` statement. `OUT` parameters are returned automatically with this form that returns a single row. `RETURN` is optional.
- Since `OUT` parameters are visible everywhere inside the function body (and can be used just like any other variable), make sure to table-qualify columns of the same name to avoid naming conflicts! (Better yet, use distinct names to begin with.)

#### Simpler yet - also to return 0-n rows

Typically, this can be simpler and faster if queries in the function body can be combined. And you *can* use [**`RETURNS TABLE()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) (since Postgres 8.4, long before the question was asked) to return 0-n rows.

The example from above can be written as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields2(_school_id int)
  RETURNS TABLE (user1_id   int
               , user1_name varchar(32)
               , user2_id   int
               , user2_name varchar(32)) AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT u1.id, u1.name, u2.id, u2.name
   FROM   users u1
   JOIN   users u2 ON u2.id = u1.id + 1
   WHERE  u1.school_id = _school_id
   LIMIT  1;  -- may be optional
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM get_object_fields2(1);
```

- `RETURNS TABLE` is effectively the same as having a bunch of `OUT` parameters combined with `RETURNS SETOF record`, just shorter.
- The major difference: this function can return 0, 1 or many rows, while the first version *always* returns 1 row.
  Add `LIMIT 1` like demonstrated to only allow 0 or 1 row.
- `RETURN QUERY` is simple way to return results from a query directly.
  You can use multiple instances in a single function to add more rows to the output.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a87286168406abdd2bc7df89acfb111)* (demonstrating both)

#### Varying row-type

If your function is supposed to **dynamically return results with a different row-type** depending on the input, read more here:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: I get `the function does not return a "COMPOSITE" type • the function does not return a SETOF table` when trying this with Hasura.

Comment: @marcellothearcane: The functions work as advertised. See the added [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a87286168406abdd2bc7df89acfb111).

Comment: Thanks, it's a problem with Hasura I think - I'm returning `SETOF <table>` which seems to work!

Answer (score 7):

If you have a table with this exact record layout, use its name as a type, otherwise you will have to declare the type explicitly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields
        (
        name text
        )
RETURNS mytable
AS
$$
        DECLARE f1 INT;
        DECLARE f2 INT;
        …
        DECLARE f8 INT;
        DECLARE retval mytable;
        BEGIN
        -- fetch fields f1, f2 and f3 from table t1
        -- fetch fields f4, f5 from table t2
        -- fetch fields f6, f7 and f8 from table t3
                retval := (f1, f2, …, f8);
                RETURN retval;
        END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using simply as a returns set of records using return query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaName.get_two_users_from_school(schoolid bigint)
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin

 return query
  SELECT id, name FROM schemaName.user where school_id = schoolid;

end;
$function$
```

And call this function as : `select * from schemaName.get_two_users_from_school(schoolid) as x(a bigint, b varchar);`

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using OUT parameter and CROSS JOIN

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields(my_name text, OUT f1 text, OUT f2 text)
AS $$
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM  table1 t1 
CROSS JOIN table2 t2 
WHERE t1.name = my_name AND t2.name = my_name;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

then use it as a table:

```
select get_object_fields( 'Pending') ;
get_object_fields
-------------------
(Pending,code)
(1 row)
```

or

```
select * from get_object_fields( 'Pending');
f1    |   f
---------+---------
Pending | code
(1 row)
```

or

```
select (get_object_fields( 'Pending')).f1;
f1
---------
Pending
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE users(user_id int, school_id int, name text);
insert into users values (1, 10,'alice')
,(5, 10,'boy')
,(13, 10,'cassey')
,(17, 10,'delores')
,(4, 11,'elaine');
```

I setted the user_id as arbitrary int. The function input parameter is the `school_id`. So if the `school_id` is 10 you hope to get the following result:

```
 user_id | name  | user_id | name
---------+-------+---------+------
       1 | alice |       5 | boy
```

So your query should be something like:

```
with a as (
select u1.user_id,
     u1.name from  users u1 
        where school_id = 10 order by user_id limit 1),
b as      
(select u2.user_id,u2.name from users u2 
        where school_id = 10  order by user_id limit 1 offset 1 )
select * from a  cross JOIN b ;
```

So let's wrap the query to the plpgsql function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    get_object_fields2(_school_id int)
  RETURNS TABLE (user1_id   int
               , user1_name text
               , user2_id   int
               , user2_name text) 
               LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$func$
DECLARE countu integer;
BEGIN
    countu := (
        select count(*) from users where school_id = _school_id);
    IF countu >= 2 THEN
        RETURN QUERY
            with a as (
            select u1.user_id,
                u1.name from  users u1 
                where school_id = _school_id 
                    order by user_id limit 1),
            b as(
                select u2.user_id,u2.name from users u2 
                where school_id = _school_id 
                    order by user_id limit 1 offset 1 )
            select * from a  cross JOIN b;
    elseif countu = 1 then
    return query
      select u1.user_id, u1.name,u1.user_id, u1.name
        from  users u1 where school_id = _school_id; 
    else 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'not found';
    end if;
END
$func$;
```