# PostgreSQL accessing the 1st element of the record

Tags: sql, postgresql, record

I have a function that returns a record type:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
          a()
          RETURNS record AS '$lib/lib', 'a'
          LANGUAGE C VOLATILE STRICT COST 1;
```

the function returns a record with two attributes: boolean and text, which I may retrieve with a select query:

```
  SELECT status, log 
  FROM a() as (status boolean, log text);
```

Is it possible somehow to acces the elements of the record without converting them with the help of `as (status, log)`? Something like `a()[0]` and  `a()[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could cast both of them to text, and make an array out of it, but I don't think it's what you're looking for:

```
with q as (
    select array[ status::text, log ] as x from a() as (status bool, log text)
)
select x[1], x[2] from q;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the column names when you create the function.  You should create the function as returning a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
      a()
      RETURNS table(status boolean, log text) AS '$lib/lib', 'a'
      LANGUAGE C VOLATILE STRICT COST 1;
```

These column names can then be used when you invoke it.

You would call this as:

```
select status, log
from a()
```

The function "knows" what the column names are.

Comment: don't status and log become the parameters of the `a()` function? I mean we want to give names to the output and not the input, right?

Comment: Is there a way to name the output? I am aware that the record type is very general and the structure is being assigned as the function is statement is beeing invoked (which is somewhat disappointing..)

Comment: that's pretty cool. With this SQL function I can retrive conventiently a column at a time:

`select status from a();`

Is it possible to access the column without the `from a()` part? Semething like `select a().status`?

Comment: @arthur . . . You can try it and find out.  I think it is much better to put it in the `from` clause, and I only recently learned that you can do what you are asking with `generate_series()`.

Comment: @Gordon-Linoff... The reason, why I was asking this question is the following. I am writing tests for my sql statements with the help of `pgTap`. in `pgTap` the testing is either done for scallar return types or for set returns. My function returs only one record, which means that I should be able to test it with a `pgtap` scallar function. However as soon as I extract the column with `select status from a()`, the answer becomes a set, and I must create my test using a `set` function :(

Comment: @arthur . . . Now I understand.  Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547672/return-multiple-fields-as-a-record-in-postgresql-with-pl-pgsql.