# Using Psycopg2 to call a Postgres procedure that returns a record

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I have a Postgres procedure whose return type is `SETOF record`. The procedure takes several parameters, including one parameter which is a list and two which are datetimes. I would like to call this procedure from psycopg2. I am getting this error message:

`a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`

We would like the columns returned from the stored proc to be dynamic (based on user input), so we don't want to use out parameters, RETURN TABLE, RETURN SETOF , or anything else that requires declaring the return type at procedure definition time. The only way to make the return columns dynamic was this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085167/75857

What is the best way of using psycopg to call a stored proc that returns a set of records? We came up with this code which seems to work, but not sure if its recommended:

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM get_fnord(%s, %s, %s) as (foo integer, bar integer)", ([12561], start, end));`

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is fine. It matches the style of what the *Postgres* doc shows for using a *function* in the *FROM* clause of a *SELECT* statement.

Their example shows it being called both with and without a *column definition list*:

```
CREATE FUNCTION distributors(int) RETURNS SETOF distributors AS $$
    SELECT * FROM distributors WHERE did = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM distributors(111);
 did |    name
-----+-------------
 111 | Walt Disney

CREATE FUNCTION distributors_2(int) RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
    SELECT * FROM distributors WHERE did = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM distributors_2(111) AS (f1 int, f2 text);
 f1  |     f2
-----+-------------
 111 | Walt Disney
```

It would appear that *psycopg2* (or perhaps the underlying *libpq* it wraps) needs the latter form, with the definition.

Doc link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to call postgres function that returns cursor.
Here is the code:

```
con = psycopg2.connect("connection string")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("BEGIN")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM **SP NAME WITH PARAMETER**;")
cur.execute("FETCH ALL from records;") // records is the cursor defined in function   
items = cur.fetchall()
```