# How to return no records found from a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, go, plpgsql

Is it possible to have a stored procedure behave exactly like a regular select query when no records are found, or is this a driver issue.

For example, with go, a query that returns no rows will return an sql.ErrNoRows error.  However, this will not:

```
create table emptytable(id int);

create function selectany() returns emptytable as $$
DECLARE
  _out emptytable;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO emptytable FROM emptytable limit 1;
  RETURN _out;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I have tried SELECT INTO STRICT, and while that raises a "query returned no rows" error, it is not the same as a non-stored procedure query.  Neither is raising NO_DATA_FOUND.

Comment: How about defining a `SET OF` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly:

*Return **one or no row** from a function and allow to do more with the returned row (if any).*

Test table:

```
CREATE TABLE emptytable(id int, txt text);  -- multiple columns
```

To return one or no **complete table row**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectany_all()
  RETURNS SETOF emptytable AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _out  emptytable;
BEGIN
   FOR _out IN
      SELECT * FROM emptytable LIMIT 1
   LOOP
     -- do something with _out before returning
     RAISE NOTICE 'before: %', _out;
     RETURN NEXT _out;
     -- or do something with _out after returning row
     RAISE NOTICE 'after: %', _out;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For a more flexible approach: return **arbitrary columns**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectany_any()
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, txt text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR id, txt IN
      SELECT e.id, e.txt FROM emptytable e LIMIT 1
   LOOP  
     -- do something with id and text before returning
     RAISE NOTICE 'before: %, %', id, txt;
     RETURN NEXT;
     -- or do something with id and text after returning row
     RAISE NOTICE 'after: %, %', id, txt;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note, the `LOOP` is **never entered** if there is no row. Accordingly you will get no `NOTICE` from my test code.

Both functions work for ***n* rows** returned as well, `LIMIT 1` is just for this particular request.

Closely related, wtih more explanation:

- [Return multiple fields as a record in PostgreSQL with PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651921/939860)

Answer (score 2):

2.5 options:

1a) If you just need to return a query, you can use `SETOF` and `RETURN QUERY`

1b) or just use language `SQL` as @ClodoaldoNeto, which returns a query natively using sql's `SELECT` stmt

2) If you need to process the result in the procedure, you must use `SETOF` and `RETURN NEXT`, ensuring you check `IF FOUND THEN RETURN;` (note lack of `NEXT`, which if given will act as a single blank row is returned)

Ideally, I'd like to not use `SETOF` for procedures known to return exactly none or 1 rows, but it seems `SETOF` is required to get a procedure to query like an sql statement from the app and have drivers recognize `NO ROWS RETURNED`

Examples below:

```
create table emptytable(id int);

create function selectany() returns setof emptytable as $$
DECLARE
  _out emptytable;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO _out FROM emptytable limit 1;
  IF FOUND THEN
    RETURN _out;
  END IF;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

create function selectany_rq() returns setof emptytable as $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT * INTO _out FROM emptytable limit 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Just use `RETURN QUERY SELECT ...` (without `INTO _out`). There are many related answers. [Try a search.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+%22return+query+select%22)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks, I looked at the search you provided but it ignores use cases where processing of the query results are needed, which in my case is the primary reason for using stored procs instead of sql embedded in the app, specifically ```SELECT INTO _out ... RETURN NEXT _out``` with the ```SETOF``` declaration seems to work fantastic.

Comment: For your 1st function `selectany()` I get `RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set`. (Testing with pg 9.1.) Your 2nd function `selectany_rq()` is missing the declaration of `_out`, but with that fixed, I still get: `ERROR:  cannot open SELECT query as cursor`. I added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments do return `setof` `emptytable`

```
create function selectany()
returns setof emptytable as $$
    select *
    from emptytable 
    limit 1
    ;
$$ language sql;
```

Plain sql can do that