# Is "raise exception" the only way to return an error from pgplsql to node-postgres?

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

Say, I have a pgplsql function (e.g. `buyItem`) which returns something (e.g. bought item parameters). In some cases I want to indicate that something went wrong so the result is empty (e.g. not enough money to buy desired item). It's just a usual result, I'd not call it an exception (and definitely would not print an error about it on the db server, as `raise exception` does).

So the question is: what's the best practice to handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options are either to raise an exception, or return a record with both success and error information:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION buyItem(itemId integer)
RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
DECLARE 
  result RECORD;
BEGIN
  IF itemId > 0 THEN
    SELECT 'purchase successful', NULL INTO result;
  ELSE
    SELECT NULL, 'purchase failed' INTO INTO result;
  END IF;
  RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

There are more examples of returning records here: [Return multiple fields as a record in PostgreSQL with PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547672/return-multiple-fields-as-a-record-in-postgresql-with-pl-pgsql)

Comment: Ok, thanks, David. So if my function actually returns a table, the second option becomes not usable.

Comment: If you're returning a table you could also consider adding an extra `error` column. But I don't believe it's possible to nest inside records or rows, so unless you wanted to do something like convert it to an array (and return something like `(error text, results buyItemResult[])`), you're out of luck.