# Node.js not recognising Exception from Postgres Procedure as an Error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a procedure in postgres which completes some validations and inserts some data. If the validations are not passed then it raises an exception.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EnrolStudentToProgram(iProgramID int, iStudentID int, dEnrolDate date, vEnrolDesc varchar(255))
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
-- Variables
    d int;  
BEGIN
--validations and inserts
    ....
    
    IF d = 0 THEN
        raise exception  
        'No assessment seq configured for the requested Program_ID: %', iProgramID;
    END IF;  
  END;  
$$;
```

I call the procedure from a node.js back end using node-postgres pool:

```
const enrolStudentInProgram = async (req, res) => {
  const { studentId, program, enrolDesc } = req.body

  if (!studentId || !program || !enrolDesc) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
  }

  try {
    const enrolled = await pool.query(
      `call EnrolStudentToProgram($1,$2,now()::date,$3::varchar(255))`,
      [program, studentId, enrolDesc]
    )
    return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Student Enrolled' })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid data received' })
  }
}
```

The procedure functions as desired when executed in pdAdmin with the exception being raised, and everything flows in node.js when there are no exceptions, but if an exception is raised in the procedure I cannot get node.js to recognise this as an error or retrieve the exception message.

How do I cause an error to be recognised and retrieve an error message in Node.js when validations fail?

Update from comments:
The console.log of enrolled is below, it is the same whether there is an exception raised or not.

```
 ~ enrolStudentInProgram ~ enrolled: Result {
  command: 'CALL',
  rowCount: null,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: undefined,
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object],
      builtins: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false,
  _prebuiltEmptyResultObject: null
}
```

Comment: What happens in the node handler when you have a postgres error?  Does it return some status code other than 201 that you could then throw?

Comment: @MattMorgan I'm not 100% sure what you mean by _node handler_. If I console log `enrolled` there is nothing in there relating to status or error, and I haven't assigned anything to `res` yet so nothing in there either.

Comment: So, `enrolled` is `undefined`, in the case of the exception, or `null`, or...what?  Is it different when the call succeeds than when it doesn't, is what I'm asking, because that could be helpful info.

Comment: @MattMorgan, sorry, understand now. No, there is no different in the output whether there is an exception or not. Detail added to the question.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972715/is-raise-exception-the-only-way-to-return-an-error-from-pgplsql-to-node-postgr

Comment: Thanks, yes I had seen that and for the moment have converted to a function and returned errors that way, but I would have thought there was a way to do it with procedures and raising exceptions. Much cleaner than having to return error info as a result and then reading/ interpreting it in node.