# Why has a query no "destination for result data" in PostgreSQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, function, authentication, stored-procedures

I'm new in postgre and I'm with a problem.
I want to great the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION autenticarusuario()
RETURNS users AS
$BODY$`
DECLARE
 login text;
 senha text;
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_user = login
            AND pass_user = senha;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION autenticarusuario()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

but I always get the message:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function autenticarusuario() line 6 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Context: PL/pgSQL function autenticarusuario() line 6 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're telling Postgres "Start executing this function, then execute this query". Postgres is complaining because you don't tell it what to do with the query results. You could either use a `SELECT INTO` statement, or you could use `RETURN QUERY` to return a single column, like the user id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION autenticarusuario()
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$`
DECLARE
 login text;
 senha text;
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT id 
                 FROM users 
                WHERE login_user = login
                  AND pass_user = senha;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
```

If you want to return multiple fields for each record, you can use a similar strategy to what is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547672/return-multiple-fields-as-a-record-in-postgresql-with-pl-pgsql) and create your own type.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague faced a similar problem. She than used **OPEN MYCURS** before the select query and **RETURN MYCURS** after the select query.