# Data commit fails for "Upsert" / Merge function when calling through Npgsql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, transactions, npgsql

I am using Npgsql 3.0.3 with Postgres 9.4. Here is my code in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_test
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  CONSTRAINT temp_test_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and the "Upsert" / merge function that returns the changed record as refcursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_save(
    v_ref refcursor,
    iv_id integer,
    v_name character varying)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
  v_ref alias for $1;
  v_id integer := iv_id;
BEGIN

  UPDATE onepm.temp_test
  SET name   = v_name
  WHERE id         = v_id;
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
  INSERT INTO onepm.temp_test
      (name)
  VALUES
      (v_name)
  RETURNING id INTO v_id;
  END IF;

  OPEN v_ref FOR
  SELECT id 
       , name
  FROM onepm.temp_test
  WHERE id = v_id;

  RETURN v_ref;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In my .net project I have the following function that returns a IDatareader:

```
public static IDataReader ExecuteReader()
        {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();

            NpgsqlTransaction _tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT onepm.test_save(@ref, @id, @name)";

            NpgsqlParameter _p = new NpgsqlParameter();
            _p.ParameterName = "@ref";
            _p.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
            _p.NpgsqlValue = "ref";
            _p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(_p);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", 1));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@name", "test"));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = "fetch all in \"ref\"";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

This all works fine, I do receice the inserted or updated record in the reader, except that the data is never committed to the table - no data found in pgAdmin. If I call the same function in pgAdmin everything works fine - records are committed:

```
SELECT onepm.test_save('v_ref', 1, 'xxxxxx');

FETCH ALL IN "v_ref";
```

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, I think you need to commit the transaction you started...!

Regardless, you may also want to look at PostgreSQL 9.5's new built-in upsert functionality...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Problem is that if I commit the transaction I loose the ability to fetch the data. Is there a way to define the refcursor "WITH HOLD"?

Comment: Well, there's no real reason for your function to return a refcursor - you can modify it to return a simple table (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html). You can then invoke your your function in a single SQL call (SELECT * FROM onepm.test_save(...)), and can remove the BeginTransaction() altogether...

Comment: Thanks, this works with the pain of having to define the return table. We need the new record for values that are calculated by the db at insert... Will Npgsql handle this in a different way with the new upsert statement?

Comment: You can also return a record (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6085167/640325). The PG 9.5 upsert functionality is documented here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29. Npgsql doesn't know or care about it in any way, it just delivers it. Not sure it's suitable for what you're trying to do though,

Comment: Returning records is semi satisfying as well since we have to modify the record type into something column like again. I come back to the initial question: Is there a way to control the commit after fetching the data from the cursor in Npgsql? It seems works fine when making the calls directly.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You'll have to call commit after finishing with the reader. NpgsqlDataReader exposes a ReaderClosed event which you can subscribe to, and commit there. It's a pretty convoluted and non-standard solution though.