# Function which renames its output parameters, according to some input parameters (prefix/suffix)

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'd like to have a function which can rename its output parameters, according to some input parameters.

I tried a few solutions to automate this task (mainly concentrated on [changing return type for function to polymorphic record variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085167/2242987)), but neither works for me. I will do appreciate any sugestions.

This problem drives me crazy, as my current setup makes me write bulk of unnecessary(?) code. 
I use this kind of functions to format date displayed in views, so it should be /dynamic/.

My current design is like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name_of(
    IN in_date date, 
    OUT mnth_date text,
    OUT qrt_date text
) AS
$func$
    BEGIN
        mnth_date =to_char(in_date ,'YYYY"M"MM');       
        qrt_date =to_char(in_date ,'YYYY"Q"Q'); 
    END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What results in having this:

```
select (name_of('2014-04-30')).*


________________________
|mnth_date  |qrt_date  |
------------------------
|2014M04    |2014Q2    |
```

My target setup, is to have result similar to this:

```
    select 
        A.*, B.*
     from
        name_of('2014-04-30','foo_prefix' ) A,
        name_of('2014-05-13','creation' ) B;

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
|foo_prefix_mnth_date   |foo_prefix_qrt_date    |creation_mnth_date     |creation_qrt_date      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2014M04                |2014Q2                 |2014M05                |2014Q2                 |
```

Currently I do heavy use of aliases, so my code looks similar to that:

```
    select 
        A.mnth_date foo_prefix_mnth_date,
        A.qrt_date foo_prefix_qrt_date,
        B.mnth_date creation_mnth_date,
        B.qrt_date creation_qrt_date
     from
        name_of('2014-04-30') A,
        name_of('2014-05-13') B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use column [aliases](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_alias_syntax.htm):

```
SELECT
    name_of('2014-04-30') AS foo_prefix_mnth_date,
    name_of('2014-05-13') AS creation_mnth_date,
    name_of('2014-06-20') AS access_mnth_date;
```

The keyword `AS` is optional, so that this also works:

```
SELECT name_of('2014-04-30') foo_prefix_mnth_date;
```

but is recommended to use it for better readability

Comment: Thanks.
I do, but i want to abandon this approach as it is not effective.
I updated my question to better describe problem.