# Dynamic select function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would i write and implement a function which selects from multiple tables dynamically based on the parameters passed to the function + other variables. The data selected would need to be returned by the function.

So far i have tried PERFORM which is challenging to get the return and also tried EXECUTE which seems to only return INTO variables and not sets. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-declarations.html. I'm almost certain this isn't a design issue as this can be done in a few lines in TSQL spocs.

Comment: The link you point to is a version that is almost 5 years past EOL. You might want to look at something current: [plpgsql declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html). In particular,  'Another way to declare a PL/pgSQL function is with RETURNS TABLE, for example:'  Also [plpgsql return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) 42.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547672/return-multiple-fields-as-a-record-in-postgresql-with-pl-pgsql

Comment: And how do i get dynamic execution into either of these return types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the approach is finding a way to store a variable and return the results of said variable should it be executed. This below does the trick and the passing of params is a simple.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo( 
) 
RETURNS TABLE ( 
     key TEXT 
    , value GEOMETRY
) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'  
SECURITY INVOKER 
AS $$ 
DECLARE 
    err1 TEXT;
    err2 TEXT;
    err3 TEXT ; 
    dyn_sql TEXT ; 
    
BEGIN 
    
 
    SELECT 
        concat(LEFT(concat( 'SELECT q.viewn, q.geom /* INTO constraint_output_temp */ FROM ( ' , string_agg(sql_parts, '') ), -11) , ') AS q' ) AS query
    INTO 
        dyn_sql
    FROM    
        (
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN 1 = 1
                     THEN  concat( 'SELECT ''', t.matviewname, ''' as viewn, ', t.matviewname, '.geom FROM ', t.schemaname, '.', t.matviewname, ' AS ', t.matviewname, ' INNER JOIN targets ON st_intersects(', t.matviewname, '.geom, targets.geom) UNION ALL ' )
                     ELSE NULL
                END AS sql_parts
                , concat(t.schemaname, '.', t.matviewname) AS obj
                , t.matviewname AS viewn
            FROM
                pg_catalog.pg_matviews AS t
            WHERE
                schemaname = 'something'     
        ) AS q
    ;
    
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE dyn_sql ; 

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS 
        err1 = MESSAGE_TEXT
        , err2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
        , err3 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT ;
    
    RETURN QUERY SELECT CONCAT( err1, err2, err3 )::TEXT ;
    
END $$ ;

SELECT * FROM foo(  ) ;
```