# 'column reference "id" is ambiguous' error on function call that uses RETURNING

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-function

I have this table with two autogenerated columns:

```
CREATE TABLE driver_orders 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    car_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    location_from GEOGRAPHY  -- generated
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS
            (create_point_geography(start_point)) stored,
    location_to GEOGRAPHY    -- generated
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS
            (create_point_geography(end_point)) stored
);
```

I am writing a postgres function that inserts a new row then returns `id`, `location_from` and `location_to`. I am following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547672/return-multiple-fields-as-a-record-in-postgresql-with-pl-pgsql)

Here is what I have come up with (unrelated parts removed):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_driver_order(
    car_id INTEGER,
    s_point VARCHAR,
    e_point VARCHAR
  )
  RETURNS TABLE (
    id INTEGER, 
    location_from GEOGRAPHY, 
    location_to GEOGRAPHY
  )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    DECLARE
    active_order_count INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    -- 1. count active orders
    --     ... omitted unrelated parts
    -- 2. check if active orders are less than two
    --     ... omitted unrelated parts

    -- 4. create order
    RETURN QUERY INSERT INTO driver_orders (
        car_id,
        start_point,
        end_point
      ) VALUES (
        car_id,
        s_point,
        e_point
      ) RETURNING id, location_from, location_to;
  END;
$$
```

Function is created successfully. But when I call it:

```
select * from create_driver_order(
    889,
  '(5581326278118 29.220418907676738)'::VARCHAR,
  '(5581326274318 29.220548907676738)'::VARCHAR
)
```

I get this error:

> column reference "id" is ambiguous

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried qualifying which id it refers to? 
RETURNING driver_orders.id, location_from, location_to;

Comment: Read [Variable substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`returns table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) the columns of that output table are defined in the scope of your function body, so your use of `returning id, location_from, location_to` could either refer to columns of the output record, or to columns of the table you're inserting to, or even something else. Just specify which one you want, explicitly. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1_eB9VvI):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_driver_order(car_id INTEGER,
                                               s_point VARCHAR,
                                               e_point VARCHAR)
  RETURNS TABLE (id INTEGER, 
                 location_from GEOGRAPHY, 
                 location_to GEOGRAPHY)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $f$
DECLARE
    active_order_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- 1. count active orders
    --     ... omitted unrelated parts
    -- 2. check if active orders are less than two
    --     ... omitted unrelated parts

    -- 4. create order
    RETURN QUERY INSERT INTO driver_orders AS d (
        car_id,
        start_point,
        end_point
      ) VALUES (
        car_id,
        s_point,
        e_point
      ) RETURNING d.id, 
                  d.location_from, 
                  d.location_to;
END $f$;
```